# SQL database does not exist jupyter notebook

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, sqlalchemy, jupyter-notebook

I am having problems with trying to use my sqlite database file in jupyter using python.  When I run the code it allows the connection, but when I try any sql code it always returns that it is not a database.  I have looked at multiple solutions and it is not the version or anything else that I am seeing.  The codes are bellow:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import pandas as pd
countrycl = create_engine('
countrycl = create_engine('sqlite:///country_club_sqlite.sql')
con = countrycl.connect()
Produce a list of facilities with a total revenue less than 1000. The output of facility name and total revenue, sorted by revenue. Remember that there's a different cost for guests and members! */

qt = con.execute('select facs.name, sum(case when memid = 0 then slots * facs.guestcost else slots * membercost end) as revenue from cd.bookings bks inner join cd.facilities facs on bks.facid = facs.facid group by facs.name having sum(case  when memid = 0 then slots * facs.guestcost else slots * membercost end) < 1000 order by revenue;')
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
DatabaseError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py in _execute_context(self, dialect, constructor, statement, parameters, *args)
   1277                     self.dialect.do_execute(
-> 1278                         cursor, statement, parameters, context
   1279                     )

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py in do_execute(self, cursor, statement, parameters, context)
    592     def do_execute(self, cursor, statement, parameters, context=None):
--> 593         cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
    594 

DatabaseError: file is not a database

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

DatabaseError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-28-0f378f600538> in <module>
----> 1 qt = con.execute('select facs.name, sum(case when memid = 0 then slots * facs.guestcost else slots * membercost end) as revenue from cd.bookings bks inner join cd.facilities facs on bks.facid = facs.facid group by facs.name having sum(case  when memid = 0 then slots * facs.guestcost else slots * membercost end) < 1000 order by revenue;')

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py in execute(self, object_, *multiparams, **params)
   1004         """
   1005         if isinstance(object_, util.string_types[0]):
-> 1006             return self._execute_text(object_, multiparams, params)
   1007         try:
   1008             meth = object_._execute_on_connection

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py in _execute_text(self, statement, multiparams, params)
   1179             parameters,
   1180             statement,
-> 1181             parameters,
   1182         )
   1183         if self._has_events or self.engine._has_events:

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py in _execute_context(self, dialect, constructor, statement, parameters, *args)
   1316         except BaseException as e:
   1317             self._handle_dbapi_exception(
-> 1318                 e, statement, parameters, cursor, context
   1319             )
   1320 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py in _handle_dbapi_exception(self, e, statement, parameters, cursor, context)
   1510             elif should_wrap:
   1511                 util.raise_(
-> 1512                     sqlalchemy_exception, with_traceback=exc_info[2], from_=e
   1513                 )
   1514             else:

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py in raise_(***failed resolving arguments***)
    176 
    177         try:
--> 178             raise exception
    179         finally:
    180             # credit to

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py in _execute_context(self, dialect, constructor, statement, parameters, *args)
   1276                 if not evt_handled:
   1277                     self.dialect.do_execute(
-> 1278                         cursor, statement, parameters, context
   1279                     )
   1280 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py in do_execute(self, cursor, statement, parameters, context)
    591 
    592     def do_execute(self, cursor, statement, parameters, context=None):
--> 593         cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
    594 
    595     def do_execute_no_params(self, cursor, statement, context=None):

DatabaseError: (sqlite3.DatabaseError) file is not a database
[SQL: select facs.name, sum(case when memid = 0 then slots * facs.guestcost else slots * membercost end) as revenue from cd.bookings bks inner join cd.facilities facs on bks.facid = facs.facid group by facs.name having sum(case  when memid = 0 then slots * facs.guestcost else slots * membercost end) < 1000 order by revenue;]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/13/4xp6)

import sqlite3
)
print(sqlite3.sqlite_version)
3.32.3
ountrycl
table_names = countrycl.table_names()
print(table_names)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
DatabaseError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py in _execute_context(self, dialect, constructor, statement, parameters, *args)
   1277                     self.dialect.do_execute(
-> 1278                         cursor, statement, parameters, context
   1279                     )

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py in do_execute(self, cursor, statement, parameters, context)
    592     def do_execute(self, cursor, statement, parameters, context=None):
--> 593         cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
    594 

DatabaseError: file is not a database

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

DatabaseError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-32-592f50a9fefe> in <module>
----> 1 table_names = countrycl.table_names()
      2 print(table_names)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py in table_names(self, schema, connection)
   2318 
   2319         with self._optional_conn_ctx_manager(connection) as conn:
-> 2320             return self.dialect.get_table_names(conn, schema)
   2321 
   2322     def has_table(self, table_name, schema=None):

<string> in get_table_names(self, connection, schema, **kw)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\reflection.py in cache(fn, self, con, *args, **kw)
     42     info_cache = kw.get("info_cache", None)
     43     if info_cache is None:
---> 44         return fn(self, con, *args, **kw)
     45     key = (
     46         fn.__name__,

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\dialects\sqlite\base.py in get_table_names(self, connection, schema, **kw)
   1609             master,
   1610         )
-> 1611         rs = connection.execute(s)
   1612         return [row[0] for row in rs]
   1613 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py in execute(self, object_, *multiparams, **params)
   1004         """
   1005         if isinstance(object_, util.string_types[0]):
-> 1006             return self._execute_text(object_, multiparams, params)
   1007         try:
   1008             meth = object_._execute_on_connection

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py in _execute_text(self, statement, multiparams, params)
   1179             parameters,
   1180             statement,
-> 1181             parameters,
   1182         )
   1183         if self._has_events or self.engine._has_events:

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py in _execute_context(self, dialect, constructor, statement, parameters, *args)
   1316         except BaseException as e:
   1317             self._handle_dbapi_exception(
-> 1318                 e, statement, parameters, cursor, context
   1319             )
   1320 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py in _handle_dbapi_exception(self, e, statement, parameters, cursor, context)
   1510             elif should_wrap:
   1511                 util.raise_(
-> 1512                     sqlalchemy_exception, with_traceback=exc_info[2], from_=e
   1513                 )
   1514             else:

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py in raise_(***failed resolving arguments***)
    176 
    177         try:
--> 178             raise exception
    179         finally:
    180             # credit to

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py in _execute_context(self, dialect, constructor, statement, parameters, *args)
   1276                 if not evt_handled:
   1277                     self.dialect.do_execute(
-> 1278                         cursor, statement, parameters, context
   1279                     )
   1280 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py in do_execute(self, cursor, statement, parameters, context)
    591 
    592     def do_execute(self, cursor, statement, parameters, context=None):
--> 593         cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
    594 
    595     def do_execute_no_params(self, cursor, statement, context=None):

DatabaseError: (sqlite3.DatabaseError) file is not a database
[SQL: SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' ORDER BY name]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/13/4xp6)
```

Comment: Tables in query uses a `cd.` qualifier. Please explain this reference.

Comment: the cd. was not necessary, what it came down to is the file I downloaded from myphpadmin was the wrong type, although it is the only way I know of to download it.  Luckily the project allowed me to use one already made, but I do not know how to make the .SQL file into a .DB file...